# How to choose a secondary hidden menu

Tags: python, selenium, quip

I want to use selenium automatically export documents

[image: expect]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

# Configuration information
email = "my_email"
password = "my_password"



def work_on():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    index_url = "https://quip.com/"
    driver.get(url=index_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div/div').click()  # click file
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]').click()  # select document
    time.sleep(2)
    ele = driver.find_element_by_id('id-7-export')  # Determine the position of the element
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(ele)
    actions.click(ele) # Export to html
    actions.perform()

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_on()
```

Error message

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_id('id-7-export')  # Determine the position of the element
```

Cannot find label can't be exported

This code contains the account and password.Please test use

Automatic login may be incorrect, please try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not found this locator: `.find_element_by_id('id-7-export')` in the web page, instead you can use `xpath`:

```
//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"] -> to export
//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="HTML"] -> to HTML
```

Try the bellow:

```
def work_on():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    index_url = "https://quip.com/"
    driver.get(url=index_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div/div').click()  # click file
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[text()="test11"]').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]').click()  # select document
    time.sleep(2)
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"]')  # Determine the position of the element
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(ele).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="HTML"]')
    actions.move_to_element(html).click(html).perform()

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()
```

Comment: ```elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"]"}```

Comment: Not sure you have landing in `test11`, I've changed with this locator: 
 `By xpath` > `//h1[text()="test11"]`

Comment: hi ``` File "C:/Users/bhhuan/Desktop/20190919/test.py", line 21, in work_on
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
NameError: name 'ActionChains' is not defined ```

Comment: Following impot: `from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains`

Comment: Welcome, glad it worked, btw my suggest you can use `WebDriverWait` instead `time.sleep(...)`, it will make your project efficient.

Comment: I have other questions.can you help me, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58005395/how-to-iterate-button-links-in-selenium