# How to iterate button links in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, quip

background:I want to export all document in quip.

I provided the account and password in the code for testing.

[image: quip]

But now I can only access one file to be exported.

I want to automate these exports.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

# Configuration information
email = "xxxxx"
password = "xxxx"



def work_on():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    index_url = "https://quip.com/"
    driver.get(url=index_url)
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div/div').click()  # click file
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[text()="test11"]').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]').click()  # select document
    time.sleep(2)
    ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"]')  # Determine the position of the element
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.move_to_element(ele).perform()
    time.sleep(1)
    html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="HTML"]')
    actions.move_to_element(html).click(html).perform()

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_on()
```

Automatic login may be incorrect, please try again.

This code can only access one document and export.

I don't know how to iterate over all document and export.

Comment: first use `find_elemens_by_xpath` with char `s` in word `elements` to search all elelements, not only first one. And when you get list with many results then use `for`-loop to work with every element on the list.

Comment: hi,I am a novice,can you write full the code?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED

Now works for subfolders too:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

# Configuration information
email = "187069474@qq.com"
password = "Huangbo1019@"


def work_on():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver72.exe')
    index_url = "https://quip.com/"
    driver.get(url=index_url)

    def get_docs(docs):
        for doc in docs:
            driver.get(doc)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]').click()  # select document
            time.sleep(2)
            ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"]')  # Determine the position of the element
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(ele).perform()
            time.sleep(2)
            html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="HTML"]')
            actions.move_to_element(html).click(html).perform()
            time.sleep(5)

    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div/div').click()  # click file
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    docs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-document-thumbnail')
    docs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in docs]
    folders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-thumbnail')
    folders = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in folders]
    get_docs(docs)
    for folder in folders:
        driver.get(folder)
        time.sleep(2)
        docs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-document-thumbnail')
        docs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in docs]
        get_docs(docs)

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_on()
```

Comment: How should it work if it still contains a secondary folder? I have created test file.

Comment: @hakukou what do you mean. Explain

Comment: hi, look this image, https://i.imgur.com/0Ujk9PY.jpg ,Folder may contain folders ,There are also documents under the new folder

Comment: hi, @Kostas Charitidis I have other questions.can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037127/selenium-simulate-mouse-wheel-pull-down-and-webdriverwait-alternative-time-sleep