# Selenium simulate mouse wheel pull down and webdriverwait Alternative time.sleep

Tags: python, selenium

I am using the quip office system

I want to use selenium to export all the documentation,Encountered many problems.

1)waiting time, I only use time.sleep,often have problems

2)To load a document, I have encountered many document that need to be scrolled down

[image: quip test file]

Like this folder contains a lot of documents, you need to scroll down to get the href

3)Because it is a human created folder, there may be a new folder under the folder and another folder under the new file.

I am a newbie, please tell me as much as possible.

A test account and password are provided in the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time

# Configuration information
email = "187069474@qq.com"
password = "Huangbo1019@"


def work_on():

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('drivers/chromedriver72.exe')
    index_url = "https://quip.com/"
    driver.get(url=index_url)

    def get_docs(docs):
        for doc in docs:
            driver.get(doc)
            time.sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]').click()  # select document
            time.sleep(2)
            ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="Export"]')  # Determine the position of the element
            actions = ActionChains(driver)
            actions.move_to_element(ele).perform()
            time.sleep(2)
            html = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="parts-menu-label" and text()="HTML"]')
            actions.move_to_element(html).click(html).perform()
            time.sleep(5)

    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header-nav-collapse"]/ul/li[9]/a').click()  # click login
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/input').send_keys(email)  # input email
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email-submit"]').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/div/input[2]').send_keys(password)  # input password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/form/button').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div/div').click()  # click file
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/a').click()  # select test
    time.sleep(2)
    docs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-document-thumbnail')
    docs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in docs]
    folders = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-thumbnail')
    folders = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in folders]
    get_docs(docs)
    for folder in folders:
        driver.get(folder)
        time.sleep(2)
        docs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('folder-document-thumbnail')
        docs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in docs]
        get_docs(docs)

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    work_on()
```

The current code can only get the second-level directory folder.

Unable to capture all document links because the mouse cannot be swiped down

Waiting time is very painful, sometimes the network is not good will give an error

The quip provided are just tests, but there will be thousands of documents in the production process.

I hope who can improve this code. This is very helpful to me. 
I am truely thankful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selenium`'s scroll feature.  The following causes the scrolling to occur to the bottom of the page:

```
 driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

More information at this post: [How can I scroll a web page using selenium webdriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986631/how-can-i-scroll-a-web-page-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: hi,Although there are no errors, it does not seem to work.